# Чем отличается iTextSharp от iText и что сейчас лучше использовать?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itextsharp, itext

В Nuget сейчас обе библиотеки имеют достаточно свежие версии.

Как я понимаю, iTextSharp  был переписан в iText 7 и теперь лучше использовать его?

Answer (score 1):

iText7 полный переписать существующий код iText. iText5 (также известный как iTextSharp) был органически растет, и руководствуясь спросом клиентов. Это привело к негативным последствиям добавления кода в разных местах, а не держать хорошо структурированной архитектуры.

iText7 не имеют этот недостаток. И был специально разработан, чтобы быть легче использовать и быстрее.